# Do we need Gradle Dependencies in GoogleSignIn in Android or is it a Deprecated approach?

Tags: android, google-signin

I am new to Android, and I was trying to Add `GoogleSignin` in my blank app.

I am following this tutorial from YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PIaGpJMCNs, which says to add Gradle dependencies as shown in "Google's official documentation". But I don't see any such dependencies given in the official documentation.

I feel I am stuck in the process. Is it that the documents shown in the video are deprecated and now we don't need to add Gradle dependencies for Google SignIn?

**I have performed the following steps:**

1) Created a project in Android Studio

2) Added internet permission in manifest

3) Created a Project in Google Developer Console

4) Generated the SHA Key and added to the official documentation form

5) Generated the `credential.json` file and pasted it into the app folder of my Android Studio App

6) Installed Google play Services

7) Now the tutorial says to add Gradle dependencies in my project as provided in the "Official Google Documentation", but, as mentioned above, I could not find any such thing. I can't find anywhere in the page which tells me anything about adding Gradle Dependencies

Comment: Glide is a image caching library, the rest you have to compile.

Comment: @HB. from where did `Glide` came in this -_- ?

Comment: @nimi0112 I looked at the video. it's the only other library he used. Like OP mentioned, he already added google play services. Did you look at the video?

Answer (score 0):

To implement GoogleSignIn follow the following simple steps:

1. Add `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'` in your app level build.gradle file.
2. Configure your project in Google console [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)
3. Follow further steps [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in)

Comment: thanks, but why "implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'  " is not mentioned in the documentation ?

Comment: and if its there please let me know where can we find it

Comment: @LearnerDhruv look here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating